# Uninstalled nautilus (default file manager)

Tags: apt, nautilus, dependencies, ppa

Before the first coffee of the day sleepy me had the great idea to uninstall nautilus.

`sudo apt remove nautilus`

Now I am unable to reinstall it.

```bsh
philipp@X1C:~$ sudo apt install nautilus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nautilus : Depends: libnautilus-extension1a (= 1:40.2-1ubuntu1) but 1:40.2-1ubuntu1ppa1 is to be installed
            Depends: nautilus-data (= 1:40.2-1ubuntu1) but 1:40.2-1ubuntu1ppa1 is to be installed
N: Ignoring file 'fman.list#' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I resolve the unmet dependencies and install nautilus again?

**Edit:**
`libnautilus-extension1a` and `nautilus-data` seem to be installed.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the problem is with `nautilus` but generally with your sources. Dependency issues are almost always coming from third-party repositories you added. Check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) how to fix.

Comment: @pLumo Thanks you where right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurred because of ppa dependencies I modified earlier:
I was able to fix it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubomir-brindza/nautilus-typeahead
sudo apt-get update
```